# How does ansible's template module render values on different hosts?

Tags: ansible

I have 3 servers, I found that I want to send files to 3 servers separately.

```
# hosts
[serverA]
192.168.1.1

[serverB]
192.168.1.2

[serverC]
192.168.1.3
```

I expect the files I want to send are as follows:

```
# serverA_files:
server = 192.168.1.1
other = 192.168.1.2, 192.168.1.3

# serverB_files:
server = 192.168.1.2
other = 192.168.1.1, 192.168.1.3

# serverC_files:
server = 192.168.1.3
other = 192.168.1.1, 192.168.1.2
```

I am preparing a template for jinja2:

```
# test.j2
server = {{inventory_hostname}}
other = ？？？ # But these two values, I don't know how to assign them,
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit**: this answer is a bit old and my ansible-fu has since grown. Although the below answer (for memory) is valid, there is a much easier way to achieve the exact same result with the `reject` filter.

```
server={{ inventory_hostname }}
others={{ groups['all'] | reject(inventory_hostname) | join(', ') }}
```

---

You need to go through all the ips you declared as `inventory names`, filter out the current ip and join the remaining ones with a coma.

The easy way to sort this out is with the [`json_query` filter](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#json-query-filter). To ease escaping and readability, I would declare the query as a variable inside the template.

```
server={{ inventory_hostname }}
{% set query = "[?@!='" + inventory_hostname + "']" %}
others={{ groups['all'] | json_query(query) | join(', ') }}
```

Comment: Error: msg: 'AnsibleError: You need to install "jmespath" prior to running json_query filter' （Is there a way to solve this problem without installing a plugin?）

Comment: You just need to `pip install jmespath`. This only has to be done on the ansible controller machine and you should be able to do it as a normal user if this is a concern. `json_query` might really be convenient for a lot of other tasks dealing with complex datastructures. You will probably have to install other python modules (on controller and/or target) as you gain experience with ansible (e.g. to use `docker_container` module...)